# Looping over XmlChildern with Coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I have a xml document:

```
<book>
  <content>
    <chapter2>

    </chapter2>
    <chapter3>

    </chapter3>
  </content>
</book>

<cffile action="read" file="file.xml" variable="myxml">
<cfset mydoc = XmlParse(myxml)>
<cfset booknodes = xmlSearch(mydoc,'book/content') >

<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(booknodes)#" index="i" step="1">

     <cfset bookXML = xmlparse(booknodes[i])>
#bookXML.content.XmlChildren[i].xmlName#
</cfloop>
```

In trying to make sure that I had the code correct I am simply trying to print out the xmlName for the element.  chapter2 and chapter3.

The loop only prints chapter2 and when I print the arraylen of booknodes it says only 1 however when I dump the variable booknodes chapter 3 node is present with all of its childern.

The loop seems to just stop after one.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing the wrong thing and you don't need the convoluted XMLSearch, etc... here:

```
<cfset booknodes = myxml.book.content>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(booknodes.XmlChildren)#" index="i" step="1">
  <cfoutput>#booknodes.XmlChildren[i].xmlName#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I had to add <cfset mydoc = XmlParse(myxml)> and then use <cfset booknodes = mydoc.book.content > and it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: XmlParse accepts a filename - i.e. `mydoc = XmlParse('file.xml')`